# How to send iot data to Oracle Iot cloud service?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, iot, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I have to send My iot data to Oracle IoT cloud service. As i Found there client Library [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/downloads/iot-client-libraries-2705514.html)

But wanted to know that if they have some sdk to do so? And also how to start with this client library,(Javascript)

Comment: By SDK you mean an npm package?

Comment: yes.I think its easy to implement by npm.

Comment: Did you see this? http://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/iot-cloud/iotgs/using-javascript-client-software-libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the clound via MQTT service and this is very similar to the code example provided at [MQTT tutorial](https://www.baldengineer.com/mqtt-tutorial.html). refer to section Arduino MQTT programming in this page.

You may also use Node-Red to connect to DB or push data via MQTT (ofcourse only if your IoT data is channeled through a device that has sufficient RAM/CPU to support Node-red (eg: Orange Pi, Raspberry Pi)

Hope this helps.